# Architecture with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, automapper

I am building a ASP.NET MVC application where I use the following flow :

**Get Entity**

1. Run Action at a controller
2. Fetch data from FactoryClass that operates against the Model(Entity Framework)
3. Get data back to the Action in the controller
4. Use AutoMapper to translate from Model object to ModelView object
5. Return the ModelView object to the strongly typed View

**Update Entity**

1. Run Action with ModelView Entity as input (DefaultDataBinder will be used)
2. Validate ModelView Entity
3. Send the ModelView object direcly to the right factory method.
4. Check if the ModelView object has id and if so fetch the Model object from database
5. Use AutoMapper to translate the incoming ModelView object to a Model object/entity. If its a update, then use the fetched Model object as destination.
6. If it is a update use Refresh Client.Wins else use Add
7. Run SaveChanges and return to the controler.

**Problem 1**

The ModelView classes is special made for the views that the controler actions is connected to (it could contain both edeting objects and lists). It´s common that several actions with diffrent views uses the same ModelView Class, that means that not all objects in the ModelView object will be used in every action/view.

As long as the View uses all the properties of ModelViewObjects that can be updated there is no problem but...

Say that we got a View where some of the properties of the ModelViewObject is not used, this ModelViewObject is sent to the factory(to be updated) where the corsponding ModelObject is fetched(from db/entity framework) and then merged with the ModelViewObject with AutoMapper. The problem here is that properties on the ModelViewObject that is not set(not used in the view) will result in a overwrite of real data in the ModelObject.

To solve this u usually use AutoMapper ForMember Ignor(), but this will be a problem when a complete ModelViewObject(all properties set) will update db.

How do you handle this? Do you have diffrent Update methods in the factorys where diffrent AutoMapper setting?

It would be nice If I could only have a method like this : UpdateMyEnityt(MyEntity entity) and this methid will update och add MyEntity object.

**Problem 2**

Where should I place the AutoMapper mappings? So far I have placed **Updates** in the factory and **Get** in the controller. I have thought of placeing the mappings in the ModelViewObject for example ModelViewObject.ToDataModel but if I do not need a complete translate(som properties is to be ignored) then I will have to do this AutoMapper else where.

How do you handle this?

**Problem 3**

Say that you have an working update method in our factory class where you use AutoMapper with som ignors to translate a ModelViewObject to a ModelView(entity framework object). Say now that we updates the database table with a new field/propertie, if we run a view that handles the ModelViewObject corsponding to this tabel but do not handle the new propertie this will mean that the propertie will always be set to null/string.empty/0. When running the regular update method in the factory there will not be a ignor on this propertie and this means that the zero value will overrite the real value.

Its a big risk that these kind of updates will be done and its a big risk that I will not remember to handle this in old code.

How do I handle this?

**Problem 4**
AutoMapper have a validation method where you can check if the mappings will be possible, right now I am having these validations where the mapping is done, should I maby put this in some other method where the validation will be executed as fast as the application starts? Else problems in the mappings will show first when using the function.

BestRegards

Comment: there is too much in this question - considering summarizing paragraphs - this is a Q&A forum, not essay-writing. :)

Comment: Yhea I know, but I hade problem to keep it shorter, there is so much that can decide what the aswear might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you should use viewModel for each view. And fetch only date that you need.
You should add facility to manual mapping for "difficult" issue.
I thing that AutoMapper is wrong way for transfer date from Db object to View Object.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I decide to use ViewModel for each view and a manual mapping there will always be problem when the business entitys is updated from database with new/changed properties. And If the application is big, then I might not find broken mappings as easy. This is ofcouse so long there is several views that uses the same business entitys.

Comment: Say that Page1 needs the view to contain the complex class MyFilters, this class contains alot of parameters. Also my Page2 needs this class. Is it wrong to ad the same class to both the views? If not, there will be alot of extra code that do more or less the same thing.

Comment: You should design you ViewModel by UI.so if you have same controls on different page.you should use same viewModel. Like: Page1 and Page2 with same properties MyFilter is view model for our pages.

Comment: And about new/changed properties, you will have this problem no matter with AutoMapper or without.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: If you are using a different View, use a different ViewModel. This way only the properties that are displayed will be automapped.

Problem 2: Different Automapper Settings in each project with

```
Project1.AutomapperSettings.Execute();
Project2.AutomapperSettings.Execute();
```

etc

in the Global.asax or similar entry point.

Problem 3: See problem 1

Problem 4: Use ValidationAttribute on viewmodel properties and let mvc take care of it

Comment: PROBLEM 1 : sounds good, PROBLEM 2: Pleas explain this, do you mean that the Mapper.Create should be where I have placed it but the Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); should be runned from the Gloval.asax? PROBLEM 3 : Okay I see PROBLEM 4 : I am not talking about the entity validation but the Mapper valdiation (Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();)

Comment: Say that Page1 needs the view to contain the complex class MyFilters, this class contains alot of parameters. Also my Page2 needs this class. Is it wrong to ad the same class to both the views? If not, there will be alot of extra code that do more or less the same thing.

Comment: Problem 2: AutoMapper mappings should be created when the application loads, as they belong to a static class and will exist for the lifetime of your application.
Problem 4: Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); should only be run in unit tests, not as a part of your application logic afaik.
Comment 2: Map ViewModel1 to Model and ViewModel2 to Model and consider inheritance for your ViewModels. Otherwise you may as well remove ViewModels altogether as you are not using them to filter / restructure your Model?

Comment: Thanks! So the masspings is not done where thay are used but where the application loads? And its this method that I will have to set tests on with AsserConfigurationsValid? Comment2 : But If I use partial View and then the same ModelView for this, could that solve the problem?